# Puppet agent fails to retrieve catalog until a file is touched

Tags: puppet

I have a very strange issue with Puppet agent v3.8.6 on Windows (also seen the issue on Linux).

Every time I run 'puppet agent -t' to do a test run I get a Error: "

Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Error: Could not find data item users in any Hiera data file and no default supplied"

Here is the weirdness:

1.) No where in my hiera config or default modules etc am I using the users module it complains about.

2.) To temporarily resolve this issue, all I have to do is touch the module manifest. i.e. touch /etc/puppet/environments/.../modules/users/manifests/init.pp. Then when I re-run the agent it works. It then works 3-4 time after that then fails again.

2a.) turns out I can touch almost any file in my modules directory to temporarily fix the issue.

This seems like some sort of caching issue, but I am now banging my head against a wall to find the root cause of the problem and how to resolve it.

I have already picked through the debug output and removed everything I can from my hiera config. Nothing seems to remove this strange issue.

Has anyone else seen behavior like this? Any hints / clues as to where I should look to solve this?

Some additional config details:

In my current setup I have 1 class that gets applied via a single level hiera hierarchy which does nothing but output some logging.

I have gone through the users module (the one named in the error) with a fine tooth comb but in any case it still complains even when it is not included in ANY config.

I suspect puppet is walking the modules directory (for caching purposes?) and the 'users' module is the first one it hits and the error is not specific to users. I plan to test this by moving the users module out of the modules directory

I haven't got any top level declarations outside of the site manifest.  As I say above, the strange thing is that I can touch any file in the modules path and the problem disappears for 3-4 cycles of the agent.

Thanks,
James

Comment: We generally like to see a [mcve].  In this case, I suspect that the process of paring down your code to produce one will reveal the problem to you, but if it doesn't, then do bring the MCVE for us to examine.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. However there is no single easy to encapsulate bit of code here. Its a behavior I am seeing and dont know the root cause. It seems to be related to puppet in general as I can modify any file in the system to temporarily resolve the issue. As such I dont know WHAT code makes sense to post. It would be hard to establish context. Happy to provide anything people might  think is relevant though. I am more curious if anyone has seen an issue like this and if lucky found the root cause

Comment: In addition... The config is as paired down as it can be... I have hiera configs which install an empty module with only notifies in them and I still get this behavior. I would like to find out if anyone else has seen this before tearing down the puppet install

Comment: "As pared down as it can be" is an empty site manifest, zero modules in the modulepath, and no ENC.  Also a clean PuppetDB if you are using PuppetDB.  All of this on the master, of course.  I'm inclined to doubt that your problem would occur in such an environment, but if it does then something is terribly broken.

Comment: As pared down as I *expect* it to be would be one or a small number of modest-size classes, data for those classes in a single-level Hiera hierarchy, and a site manifest that declares nothing but an appropriate one of those classes (and no ENC).  Were it me, I would set up a dedicated environment in which to build that (and/or tear down another environment's contents to that).  What I describe is small enough that you could reasonably edit it into the question.

Comment: As to localizing the problem, inasmuch as the error message complains about a data item named `users`, I would be looking for a class that has a parameter by that name, and no declared default value for that parameter.

Comment: Also, be on the lookout for declarations at top level (outside any class definition, defined type definition, or node block).  Such declarations are allowed, but they are extremely poor form outside your site manifest.  In principle they apply to every node, but they are not necessarily *evaluated* for every node.  Weird caching effects often follow.

Comment: You are correct. I have 1 class that gets applied via a single level hiera hierachy which does nothing but output some logging. I have gone through the users module with a fine tooth comb but in any case it still complains even when it is not included in ANY config. I havent got any top level declarations outside of the site manifest.  The strange thing is that I can touch any file in the modules path and the problem disappears for 3-4 cycles of the agent.

Comment: I will update the question with that detail

Comment: As you suggest... We are thinking of building a new puppet master and config bit by bit and testing as we go. But given our environment I'd rather see if this is some sort of known problem before we take drastic measures. It appears maybe this is something specific to us. S

Comment: I am inclined to think that the problem is specific to your manifest set, yes.  The more I hear and the more I think about it, the more I suspect a top-level declaration such as I warned about.  Always remember that manifest files are not a unit of encapsulation or scoping for Puppet.